# How do I remove the original release date tag (TORY in ID3 v2.3) from a mp3 file using eyeD3 and Lubuntu?

Tags: mp3, lubuntu, frame

How do I remove the original release date tag (TORY in ID3 v2.3) from a mp3 file using eyeD3 and Lubuntu?  I have tried eyeD3 --remove-frame TORY file.mp3 without success. I've also tried --remove-object, but then get an error message from eyeD3.

Answer (score 1):

That's likely because your file has ID3 v2.4. "Original release year" is `TDOR` in ID3 v2.4. Try `eyeD3 --remove-frame TDOR file.mp3` - worked for me.